# How to edit non-suspect recognized text in Acrobat Pro?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a scanned document in PDF format.

I asked Adobe Acrobat Pro XI to recognize the text.

When I copy all the text to a Word document some of the text is not recognized correctly.

**Problem:**
Acrobat only lets me edit the "suspect" texts, but I can't find how to edit the non-suspect text, which Acrobat thinks has recognized it correctly.

Does anyone know how to edit any or all of the text recognized by Acrobat, not just what it considers "suspect"?

**Note:**
I do not need to change what appears on the screen, only to tell Acrobat what the correct text is, so that when I publish my PDF file, users can select the correct text.

Scanning the document at higher resolution is not a possible solution in my case.

If there is an open-source application that will do this I would be happy to try it out.

Thanks in advance!